# How to reload PowerShell after installing poshgit from script?

Tags: git, powershell, chocolatey, posh-git

I'm having troubles to find a way to get git and poshgit working after installing it through a script using chocolatey without closing the powershell console.

Here is what my script currently looks like.

```
Function InstallChocolatey {
    iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
    refreshenv  #needed to make poshgit install succesfully without restarting Powershell
    Write-Output "Chocolatey installed and configured."
}

Function InstallSoftware {
    choco install git --params='/NoShellIntegration' -y
    choco install poshgit -y
    . $profile   #reload profile
    Write-Output "Software installed and profile reloaded"
}

InstallChocolatey
InstallSoftware
```

When I close Powershell and restart it everything works as expected. But as my script should later continue executing git stuff I would really like to find a solution to make it work without closing the Console.

From what I found on Stackoverflow and other sites using

```
. $profile
```

should reload the Profile. But unfortunately I my case it doesn't seem to have any effect. I tried to use refreshenv again.

My profile file currently only contains one line

```
 Import-Module 'C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-a4faccd\src\posh-git.psd1'
```

I also tried adding -force at the end of the line but nothing changed.

I'm pretty new to Powershell, so please bear with me... :)

Comment: Required restart is required.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers so what you say there is no way around a manual restart?

Comment: its not required, for me `. $profile` works. And I'm talking specifically about choco

Comment: You could try `start powershell.exe; exit`. I doubt you'll get poshgit to work without starting a new PowerShell instance.

Comment: I think the restarting part allows to reload environment variables, which might be useful for `poshgit`?

Comment: @4c74356b41 can you confirm it works for you also with poshgit?

Comment: @sodawillow I actually tried it with refreshenv as well which is supposed to reload the environment variables but that didn't change a thing.

Comment: for posh git you can do this: `. 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\posh-git\0.6.1.20160330\profile.example.ps1'` or something like that, just load that file into memory

Comment: @4c74356b41 thanks for the hint. I found the file at `C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-a4faccd\profile.example.ps1`
Loading it gives me these
`WARNUNG: git not in path
WARNUNG: Could not find ssh-agent
WARNUNG: posh-git's profile.example.ps1 will be removed in a future version.
WARNUNG: Consider using Add-PoshGitToProfile -StartSshAgent instead.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments above I was able to get it to work without restarting PowerShell (see script below)!

The key elements needed to make it work are:

**Refresh the environment variables** after installing Chocolatey and Git/Posh Git

```
refreshenv
```

In Order to make Git work without PS restart temporarily **add Git to path**

```
$env:path+='C:\Program Files\Git\cmd'
```

and last but not least **reload Posh Git Profile** (as suggested by @4c74356b41)

```
. C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-a4faccd\profile.example.ps1
```

The complete script (improvements are welcome!):

```
    Function InstallChocolatey {
    iwr https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 -UseBasicParsing | iex
    #choco feature enable -n autoUninstaller
    refreshenv
    Write-Output "Chocolatey installed."
}


Function InstallSoftware {
    choco install git --params='/NoShellIntegration' -y
    $env:path+='C:\Program Files\Git\cmd'
    Write-Output "Git installed"
    choco install poshgit -y
    refreshenv
    Write-Output "Posh Git installed"
}

Function WriteSSHKeys { #Writing SSH keys to the user directory
}

Function SetupSSH {
    . C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-a4faccd\profile.example.ps1
}

InstallChocolatey
InstallSoftware
WriteSSHKeys
SetupSSH
```

Comment: Using `. C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-a4faccd\profile.example.ps1` to reload the Posh Git Profile actually throws a warning and suggests to use `Add-PoshGitToProfile -StartSshAgent` instead. Unfortunately I was unable to get it to work using the way Posh Git suggests it.

Answer (score 0):

Only this worked for me.

```
$Env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")
```

Source: https://shellgeek.com/powershell-refresh-environment-variables/